# Sql select the elements match to array and display them in a row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with multiple checkbox where customers choose one or more item

I pass value to a page php where with statement select, I fetch  price and image of items  selected from db.

```
ID | Name | Price | Images  | item
1  | bob  | 10    | link    | a
2  | bob  | 5     | link    | b
3  | bob  | 5     | link    | c
4  | bob  | 5     | link    | d
```

I'd like display the result of items chosen in a row like:

```
bob   a b
```

The code below don't me allow to see this result when the customer choose one more item.

```
    // $_POST['choices'] array 
$result = count($_POST['choices']);

require("config.casa.php"); //file connection db


try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_Server;dbname=$DB_DBName",$DB_Username,$DB_Password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++){
        $po="SELECT  name, item, price, images  FROM my-tb WHERE item ='".$_POST['choices'][$i]."'";
        $rpo=$dbh->prepare($po);
    $rpo->execute();
$pol = $rpo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<ul class=\"tab\"><li class=\"col1\">"."name"."</li>";
    echo "<li class=\"col2\"><p class=\"two\"><h3>&euro; ".$pol['price']."</h3></p>"; 
        echo "<p class=\"lin\"><strong><span class=\"up\">".$pol['images']."</strong></p>";
        <li class=\"col3\">".$row["item"]."</li></ul>
            }
    $dbh = null;
     }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I also tried execute the statement fecth out of cycle for but I get the last item and not the all of them from variable `$_POST['choices']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do here is use the `IN CLAUSE`. Convert the `$_POST[]` to a comma separated string.

```
$choices = implode(', ', $_POST['choices']);

SELECT name, item, price, images FROM `my-tb` WHERE item IN ($choices)
```

Which will produce a query like:

```
SELECT name, item, price, images FROM `my-tb` WHERE item IN (a,b,d)
```

This will also make it so you don't loop over your `$_POST` and execute multiple queries needlessly.

**Side note**

I'm not sure if your actual table is named `my-tb` but if you have `hyphens` in your table name you must use `backticks` to encapsulate the string name.

Comment: I've tested your query with "in clause"  in panel phpmyadmin and it's displayed  the correct results and an alert "This table does not contain a unique column".

Also when I try to execute the page php, echo statement  display only a single item instead of all items.
In my question early my gol was to display all the items chosen from customer.
Maybe J've wrong the code php or the structure of the table.

The real name of table is without hyphens, thanks for the note

Answer (score 0):

In this query statement:

```
$po="SELECT  name, item, price, images  FROM my-tb WHERE item ='".$_POST['choices'][$i]."'";
```

you can use `item='item 1' or item='item 2' or ....`
Complete code for creating statement is as follows:

```
$condition="";
$count=count($_POST['choices']);
$i=0;
foreach($_POST['choices'] as $value) { $i++;
    if($i<$count) {
        $condition.="item='".$value."' or ";
    } else {
        $condition.="item='".$value."'"; //Last element should not contain or at the end
    }
}
$po="SELECT  name, item, price, images  FROM my-tb WHERE ".$condition;
```

Comment: But why? This is exactly what the `...IN` clause exists for.

Comment: Yes, just another way of getting the same result. But once I stuck with IN as my post data contained special characters. OR helped me to get out. For numeric and alphabet data, I agree IN is always the best.